# sql server minus one day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a server with SQL Server 2008 R2 installed in it. This server is used as a D -1 Database, in other words, the database it is one day behind from production server.

The problem is that my production database has more than 300GB and the daily restore is becoming an issue for the team who needs this server, because the job isn't finished before the morning day.

Is there some solution that replace the daily full backup, some kind of replication with delay ?

Comment: SQL Server Replication , Log shipping is another option.

Comment: You might look into LiteSpeed for your backup/restore. Much faster and you can do table by table restores too.

Comment: What sort of activity will you have against D-1?  Will it be read-only, read/write or purely as a warm standby for DR purposes?

Comment: Michael, it is a read/write database, used to some final development tests and also as a research database by an internal team.

Comment: If its read/write, then replication might be your best bet. You can use snapshot replication since you'll be changing data at the destination, then you just schedule the snapshot during off hours.

Comment: @JoseRocha: Do you intend to say that writes to the D-1 database will propagate back to the original? That is the intent of Michael Green's question I believe.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: The writes will not propagate back to the production database. I believe, Nabil's idea is a good one to try it.

Comment: _Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use replication.” [Now they have two problems](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/transactional-replication-change-tracking-data-capture/)._

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith: One-way replication is only half the problem of two-way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restoring a daily *full* backup, you could:

1. Take weekly full backups of production, restoring them to the `D-1` server the next day.
2. Take daily differential backups of production, restoring them to the `D-1` server the following day.

The daily restores from the differential backup will be much faster than restoring the entire database each day.

I'd advise against using replication for this; as @Mark Storey-Smith said, you will now have two problems to manage instead of one.

Comment: How I will restore a daily differential backup without the full backup ?

Comment: You'd restore the full backup once per week.  You really don't need a full backup *daily*.

Answer (score 0):

A software free solution would be to speed up your backups.  I sped my backups up dramatically by specifying multiple targets for the the backup.  You can experiment with how many to use to get best results.  For a database that large, I use 20 backup files.

BACKUP DATABASE (DBName) TO DISK = (Path to file 1), DISK = (Path to file 2), .

You might also look at what else is going on during the time of your backup, if other backups are firing off to the same place at the same time or not.